# How to check it client is already logged in?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I’m currently creatin a chat app for iOS with Quickblox service and I need to check if user  is already logged in so I can skip login process. What approach should I use?

When I was using Layer messaging service I could checked this with method:

```
LYRClient *client = [LYRClient sharedClient]
if ( [client isAuthorized]) {
}
```

`
Regards, Klemen

Answer (score 1):

With Chat iOS API you can do the next:

```
BOOL isLoggedIn = [[QBChat instance] isLoggedIn];
```

Comment: Not available now

Answer (score -1):

You could use an NSUserDefaults saved with a bool value of either YES or NO. when the user first signs in, set it to YES.

Comment: download this app, it uses NSUserDefault to remember several things such as highscore: https://t.co/O0sO8pYCkI